# Can't find a way to replicate this border

Tags: html, css

I want to replicate the border around "Contact details:". I've been searching everywhere but I didn't find anything that helped me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw1LK.png

Comment: this is html element `fieldset`

Comment: Dude or dudess please...!!! Add the code and explain exactly what you mean by "replicate the border". The png is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fieldset and legend will take care of this for you:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Contact Details:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text"><br> 
  Password: <input type="text"><br> 
  Email: <input type="text">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fieldset tag does that automatically.

```
<form>
   <fieldset>
       <!-- code -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```